# NodeJS async/await not waiting for previous request response

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

```
function getData(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.post({
            url: baseurl,
            data: input
        }).done(function (result) {
            resolve({ code: 200, data: result });
        }).fail(function (result) {
            resolve({ code: 400, data: result });
        });
    });
}
```

On key press I called following function with input search parameter but problem is second request/response get before first request/response come.

```
$("#searchText").on("keyup", async function () {
       let search = $.trim($(this).val());
       let result = await getData({ search: search });
});
```

Comment: Please comment before down vote If you are do not understand my question.

Comment: Please add your key press function

Comment: @JanithKasun I added my keypress function.

Comment: which second request are you referring to in your code?

Comment: When I write text in to textbox it give perfect response. But when I press backspace quickly for clear all text then it give me first response for blank string response then give first request which I typed text.

Comment: You basically need throttling or debouncing logic. The differing times it takes on your server to respond  to the requests means the results are not guaranteed to come in the order you sent the requests.

Comment: @mtkopone await/async does not give guarantee for FCFS(First Come First Served)?

Comment: I think async await will just make sure that the code of line after `let result..` (in your case, there is none above) will be executed after the promise is resolved. But your browser thread is still active and receiving keyup events.. async/await won't make sure that those concurrent awaits are resolved sequentially.

Comment: Yes async/await does, but nothing inside jQuery .on() guarantees order or completion of async functions. So your "keyup" is called many times, and the different invocations complete in any order they happen to. Generally, it's best practice to 1) throttle so you only send the POST when e.g. 400ms have elapsed without user input, and 2) keep track of the last request you send, and only process it's response (so responses to older requests are discarded).

Comment: How are Node and client-side jQuery code related in this question? *await/async does not give guarantee for FCFS(First Come First Served)?* - it guarantees if you chain promises. That you use `async` as a callback creates a bunch of promises that aren't related to each other. async..await is syntactic sugar for promises, it doesn't make your code work as you want by magic.

Answer (score 0):

As mtkopone mentioned in the comment you have to use a debounce logic to do this. Even though the await/async guarantee the  FCFS(First Come First Served), it is only inside the same async function.

Here in each keyup event a new instance of anonymouse async function is created and each await stays independently.

You always have to remember that await/async does not do any magic

```
 await x = y()
```

is equals to

```
 y.then(x => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's *a* way to fix that:

```
let latestSearch = "";

function getData(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.post({
            url: baseurl,
            data: input
        }).done(function (result) {
            resolve({ code: 200, data: result, search: input.search });
        }).fail(function (result) {
            resolve({ code: 400, data: result, search: input.search });
        });
    });
}

$("#searchText").on("keyup", function() {
       let search = $.trim($(this).val());
       latestSearch = search;
       let result = await getData({ search: search });
       if (result.search === latestSearch) {
        // do something with the data...
       }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For every keyup, you are posting a http request asyncly. In this case, you can set a global variable for your ajax request and if a new request triggered, you can abort the prievious request.

For ex.,

```
var test = null;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(test){ test.abort(); test = null }
    test = $.post(); // your post request
}
```

In the above example, I triggered 10 ajax request asyncly, but only last request will be posted.other request will be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel or ignore requests if you no longer want the response. Responses can arrive in any order at all, and after any amount of time if you don't set a timeout.

The best solution is to cancel requests if the results aren't useful anymore. You have a few options:

1. Cancel the previous request when making a new request (`xhr.abort`)
2. Cancel older requests that haven't finished when receiving a new response

Example:

```
$("#searchText").on("keyup", async function () {
     if (xhr) xhr.abort();
     let search = $.trim($(this).val());
     let result = await getData({ search: search });
});
```